# Remote Push notifications actions

Tags: swift2, apple-push-notifications

I created a code that receive remote push norification, this code is worked ok. Now I need to add two "buttons" that swip left and do a action. I know  that this below code is used to indetify the action

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {  

    if identifier == "optin1" {  
        //do something  
    }  
    else identifier == "option2" {  
        //do something  
    }  

    completionHandler()  
}
```

But I dont knew how to create the buttons to swip left. How can I do it

This is my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool   
{   
    // Override point for customization after application launch.   
  let types:UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge]  


    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()   
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil))  

    initLocationManager()   

    return true   

}   
func application(application: UIApplication,    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {   
    //print(error)   
}   

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {   

    print(deviceToken)   

}   


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotificationuserInfo userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {   
    print(userInfo)   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Update:* new version **Swift 4** compatible. This example was adapted from this amazing tutorial https://cocoacasts.com/actionable-notifications-with-the-user-notifications-framework

1. Configure User Notification Center

   ```
   import UserNotifications
   ...
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
   ```
2. Define Actions

   ```
   let actionReadLater = UNNotificationAction(identifier: Constants.Action.readLater,
                                              title: "Read Later",
                                              options: [])
   ```
3. Define Category

   ```
   let tutorialCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: Constants.Category.tutorial,
                                                 actions: [actionReadLater],
                                                 intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                 options: [])
   ```
4. Register Category

   ```
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([tutorialCategory])
   ```
5. Schedule local notifications by instance from an IBAction

   ```
   // Request Notification Settings
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (notificationSettings) in
       switch notificationSettings.authorizationStatus {
       case .notDetermined:
           self.requestAuthorization(completionHandler: { (success) in
               guard success else { return }

               // Schedule Local Notification
               self.scheduleLocalNotification()
           })
       case .authorized:
           // Schedule Local Notification
           self.scheduleLocalNotification()
       case .denied:
           print("Application Not Allowed to Display Notifications")
       case .provisional:
           print("provisional")
       }
   }
   ```

---

> previous version

You can copy&paste this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

1. Create the action

   ```
   // NOTFICATION
   let incrementAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
   incrementAction.identifier = "HI_ACTION"
   incrementAction.title = "Hi!"
   incrementAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
   incrementAction.authenticationRequired = false
   incrementAction.destructive = false
   ```
2. Create the category

   ```
   let counterCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
   counterCategory.identifier = "HELLO_CATEGORY"
   ```
3. Associate action and category

   ```
   counterCategory.setActions([incrementAction],
                              forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
   counterCategory.setActions([incrementAction],
                              forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
   ```
4. Registration

   ```
   let categories = NSSet(object: counterCategory) as! Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>
   let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: categories)
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
   ```
5. The last step is only for demostration

   ```
   let notification = UILocalNotification()
   notification.alertBody = "Hey!"
   notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
   notification.fireDate  = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
   notification.category  = "HELLO_CATEGORY"

   UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
   ```

> When the app is launched you have to push <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Here's a [link to an example](http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/06/11/ios9-notifications-and-text-input/)

Comment: can u convert registration section in swift 4 version? there are so many things changed.